How to map chunk.js file to ts or tsx file or How can I make sure that when I export har file , it will contain source of tsx file instead of chunk.js
so I wan to get initiator along with file from which it was called. When I observe nw calls in dev tools I can see function along with ts or tsx file from which It was made. But when export har file and open it, it doesn't contain source of ts or tsx file. Instead it contains a source of one of the cunk.js
I searched for various tools but none of them actually giving the initiator of function call.
I am expecting way where I can get initiator i.e. request call stack along with file name with ts or tsx.
I can't do this manually as it's a big application
Network Tab-Browser Dev tools ==>
Network Tab-Browser Dev tools
What I see in har file ==>
http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-common_temp_node_modules_pnpm_one_of_my_package_name_4-bfa584.chunk.js

